# iOS view positioning depending on screen size using constraints

Tags: ios, xcode6, interface-builder, constraints, screen-size

I have been reading documentation/tutorials and playing around with constraints in Xcode and still can achieve what I need.

The issue is that I need to position views (labels, images) and spread them vertically depending on the screen size of the device (focusing on iPhone for now). The css equivalent would be to use margins with percentages.

The labels/images, images don't need to grow or shrink.

As an example I have this in my Interface Builder.
[image]

To illustrate the problem I have constraints from top to bottom as follows:

- Top image has a "Vertical Space Constraint" (or Top Space) to the "Top Layout Guide.Bottom" of 63
- The "Membership" label has "Top Space" of 32
- The Membership # has "Top Space" of 16
- The white view has "Top Space" of 32 and bottom of 16

  - The imageview has "Top Space" of 32
  - The label has "Top Space" of 32
  - The button has "Top Space" of 20

This measures are correct for the iPhone 6. Now what I have been trying to achieve is to fit the same information in a smaller screen (iPhone 3.5 and 4 inch) by contracting the constraints values. I've tried using the multiplier but didn't work (or didn't know how to use it properly). I tried adding constraints to wAny hCompact but only worked for one of the constraints (top image to top margin), all the other constraints got overridden.

So this is how it looks in iPhone 6.

[image]

And this is how I want it to look in iPhone 4 (3.5 inch).
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey so in such cases i outlet the NSLayoutConstraints in their corresponding ViewController and i start manipulating them based on the screen size at runtime , usually in the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear , for your case i will assume some facts and show you a small example :

1. you want the top constraint of the top image to be 10% of the total height of the view
2. you want the top constraint of the membership label to be 7% of the total height of the view .
3. you want the top constraint of the membership hash to be 5% of the total height of the view .
4. you want the top constraint of the white view to be 7% of the total height of the view and the bottom to be 5% of the total height of the view .
5. you want the top constraint of the image to be 7% of the total height of the view .
6. you want the top constraint of the label to be 7% of the total height of the view .
7. you want the top constraint of the button to be 6% of the total height of the view .
   so based on those assumptions i would do the following :

   ```
    -(void)myLayOutMethod
    {
       //here you set the percentage of every constraint of the view . 
       CGFloat screenHeight = self.view.frame.height ; 
       CGFloat topImageConstraintValue = screenHeight/0.10f ;
       CGFloat topMembershipLabelConstraintValue = screenHeight/0.07f ;
       CGFloat topMembershipHashConstraintValue = screenHeight/0.05f ;
       CGFloat topWhiteViewConstraintValue = screenHeight/0.07f ; 
       CGFloat bottomWhiteViewConstraintValue = screenHeight/0.05f ; 
       CGFloat topImageConstraintValue = screenHeight/0.07f ; 
       CGFloat topLabelConstraintValue = screenHeight/0.07f ; 
       CGFloat topButtonConstraintValue = screenHeight/0.06 ;

       //now you start making changes to those constraints .
       self.topImageConstraint.constant = topImageConstraintValue;
       self.topMembershipLabelConstraint.constant = topMembershipLabelConstraintValue ;
       self.topMembershipHashConstraint.constant = topMembershipHashConstraintValue ;
       self.topWhiteViewConstraint.constant = topWhiteViewConstraintValue ;
       self.bottomWhiteViewConstraint.constant = bottomWhiteViewConstraintValue ; 
       self.topImageConstraint.constant = topImageConstraintValue ; 
       self.topLabelConstraint.constant = topLabelConstraintValue;
       self.topButtonConstraint.constant = topButtonConstraintValue ; 
       [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; 
    }
   ```

   off course all of these percentages are dummy values you can change them as you want , and another thing making outlets of NSLayoutConstraint is the same as making outlets from any other UIKit control , you simply find the constraint and drag it to your class

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible using only IB. Wanted to avoid this but it did look like it was the only option. Will implement and mark as answer once confirmed. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can't we do it in interface builder instead of writing codes?